# Firebase Function: how to expose a function ending with ".html"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

In order to get the domain verified by Google Pub-Sub, I have to expose a function from Firebase Functions that will be called `googledf40f9f3a4466bd2.html` (so that Google will be able to download the contents of `https://us-central1-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/googledf40f9f3a4466bd2.html` and verify them).

I tried many options, none of them worked:

`exports.googledf40f9f3a4466bd2.html = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {`
`exports.googledf40f9f3a4466bd2%2Ehtml = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {`
`exports.'googledf40f9f3a4466bd2.html' = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {`

How do I get the `https://us-central1-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/googledf40f9f3a4466bd2.html` URL work (and return some hard-coded string)?

Comment: Are you using Firebase Hosting? If so, it's much easier to just put an (empty) file named `googledf40f9f3a4466bd2.html` in your project and deploy it.

Comment: Eventually I worked around it (in a very ugly way), but your suggestion looks to be something that would've worked! Thanks.

Comment: If you got it working in another way, please post that as an answer so that others can benefit from your experience (and potentially suggest a less ugly way).

Comment: The pub-sub thingy belonged to user1, while the firebase belonged to user2. So I logged in to Firebase as user2 and added permissions to user1. This way user1 could access both the pub-sub and the Firebase. Then I used the Firebase Function built-in ability to listen to events from pub-sub: `exports.testPubSub = functions.pubsub.topic('my_topic').onPublish(event => {`, and it worked. Since both belong to the same user, there was no need to "prove" that I own the domain.